# google sites last accessed date

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script to list google sites in our domain, I have a script that returns all the sites and owners, but we also would like to get the last accessed date of the sites, it there anyway to get that info from the API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this information is captured by Google Sites, but you may want to investigate enabling Google Analytics on your site and use the Analytics service in Apps Script to get access information.